# Jenkins - how to conditionally choice parameter

Tags: jenkins

I want to add to dependence parameter: boolean and choice.

Is it possible after checking boolean parameter to to see choice dropdown with posibility to choose another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Uno choice plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Uno+Choice+Plugin). It will help to select 2 levels of your choice.

Comment: Multijob plugin allows parametrized job. but it helps single level of parameter selection

Comment: Thanks Mahi. It was helpfull